# Search Intent in Android (for Evernote)

Tags: android, search, android-intent, evernote

I was trying to create an intent in Android that would search in the Evernote app for a specific keyword, but the documentation that the Evernote site mentions doesn't seem to be available, so I tried writing it on my own, but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I have now:

```
final String ACTION_EVERNOTE = "com.evernote.action.SEARCH_NOTES";
String KEYWORD = "hoi";
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(ACTION_EVERNOTE);
i.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH, KEYWORD);
startActivity(i);
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here? Right now it just performs a search with an asterisk, which is the default, so it probably just ignores the ACTION_SEARCH part. Is there an error in that part of my intent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this, with the `String` called `QUERY`, as it's called in the `SearchManager` documentation:

```
final String ACTION_EVERNOTE = "com.evernote.action.SEARCH_NOTES";
String QUERY = "hoi";
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(ACTION_EVERNOTE);
i.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH, QUERY);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: what difference it makes with variable name changes ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller It's the name specified in the Intent, therfore, it only accepts that name as the query.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the answer above. There is a new tiny library to send these Intents to the Evernote core app.

https://github.com/evernote/android-intent